# Countifs with two options

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to use a *countifs* to count the places where a store number has either "UE" **or** "RX" attached to it (in addition to if it matches one other piece of criteria).  So for example the criteria would be something like "A16= *criteria* & "500UE" or "600RX".

Here is the formula I have currently:

```
=COUNTIFS('AUDIT 1'!$C$3:$C$121,$A16,'AUDIT 1'!$A$3:$A$121,"=*UE")
```

Now I need to add something to the end of this to the effect of:

```
,'AUDIT 1'!$A$3:$A$121,"=*RX"
```

But simply adding that results in no count obviously.  I understand that, but I'm not sure what revision (or different formula entirely) I should try.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for the help guys.  I'll play with both of these, but since posting I don't think I'll be using my original plan after all.  I do appreciate the help though!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it ins a SUM() and use an array `{}`.

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS('AUDIT 1'!$C$3:$C$121,$A16,'AUDIT 1'!$A$3:$A$121,{"*UE","*RX"}))
```

It basically does two COUNTIFS and sums the two together.

Answer (score 1):

I like Scott Craner's answer, but perhaps you might find it simpler to just add a second countif

```
=COUNTIFS('AUDIT 1'!$C$3:$C$121,$A16,'AUDIT 1'!$A$3:$A$121,"=*UE")+COUNTIFS('AUDIT 1'!$C$3:$C$121,$A16,'AUDIT 1'!$A$3:$A$121,"=*RX")
```

(Edited - originally said Scott's proposal used an array formula, which it does not)

Comment: The below is not an array formula.  It does not need to be entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  In fact it is exactly the same as your formula, just summarized.  There is absolutely no difference in speed.  Mine is just shorthand.  It runs both countifs and sums them together.